# How can I set the getDownloadURL to a variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using angularFireStorage (in my Ionic app).

I am having some success, for instance, I can look at my `console.log(res)` to click the link in my console to view a belt image. I cannot save it to a variable however, which is the issue. Ultimately I would like to use the image tag and link the belt image using `src`. Here is my code:

```
const ref = this.storage.ref('belts/');

ref.listAll().subscribe(belt=> 
    belt.items.forEach(item=> printImage(item))
)

function printImage(imageRef){
    let temp = imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    
    temp.then(res=> {
        console.log(res)
        this.mySRCs.push(res)
    })
}
```

and how I am testing it.

`<img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(mySRCs[0])"/>`

and the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'mySRCs' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mySRCs' of undefined
```

I feel like I did something similar a month or two ago but this time I cannot see the image in my app. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably did save it to a varible.  Are you sure this isn't just a problem with the fact that getting a download URL is an asynchronous operation that doesn't complete immediately?  What if you add some logging to see the order in which things execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with using the 'this' keyword within your 'printImage' function.

You either need to do:

belt.items.forEach(item=> printImage.bind(this, item))

or assuming you have a...

const mySRCs = [];

then you just pass the field as an argument to the printImage function...

belt.items.forEach(item=> printImage(item, mySRCs))

and instead of using 'this' inside the function, you use...

```
function printImage(imageRef, mySRCs){
  let temp = imageRef.getDownloadURL();

  temp.then(res=> {
    console.log(res)
    mySRCs.push(res) //<--- remove this
  })
}
```